# rig for hardsurface deformation

Tags: mesh, rigging, splines

I'm trying to build a simple rig in order to deform a rectangular prism (simple mesh for the time being), but it needs to have its deformation locked to just one an axis. The resulting mesh should be as if we had operated in a mesh level using a shear operator.

How should I build the rig to accomplish the resulting deformation using armatures? I've tried with all kind bone and object modifiers but none gives me a precise deformation.

[image]

Comment: try with shape keys

Comment: Indeed, shape keys could do the job, but this is intended to deform huge quantities of instanced objects. Shape keys affect all instances at the same time, I can not use different shape keys on two objects with same mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this rig should do nicely!
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to replicate it but with no success, can you share a file or give some detail on how to do it? thanks

Comment: I don't know how to share in here! so here is what you do: do the bones and object and add handles assign top versts to top bone and bottom to bottom bone and setup IK or do auto ik and move handles.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/q0lw6zo3w8egyxn/Weekends-exampel-01.blend/file

Comment: maybe precise that you've enabled the Auto-IK option (in Pose mode, top menu bar > Pose Options)